# DOJO Event Handler not working

Tags: dojo

red a 
I have registered a Event Handler With a HTML Component , but its not working , could anybody please help me on this :

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.event.*");
        function openAlert(evt) {
        alert("Hello!  This is an alert from Dojo!");
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="para">This is a paragraph.</p>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var para = dojo.byId("para");
      dojo.event.connect(para, "onclick", openAlert);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thank You .

Answer (score 3):

it would be better if you add on click handler in `dojoAddOnLoad`.

Code:

```
function onClickHandler(event) {
    alert('clicked!')
}

    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        dojo.connect(dojo.byId('para'), 'onclick', onClickHandler);
    });
```

[Your working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dK8H4/10/)

Answer (score 3):

First, `dojo.require("dojo.event.*");` is not correct.   I don't think you can load wild-cards to `dojo.require`.  Also `dojo.event` appears to be deprecated: it is only `dojo.connect` now.

You are loading from CDN (xd = cross-domain).  It is an "async" load -- which means that when your code is run, the Dojo library may not be loaded yet.

You need to put your user code into `dojo.addOnLoad` or the newer style `dojo.ready`.  These are called after all Dojo modules are downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use dojo.connect instead. You just need to import dojo, no extra packages, and change dojo.event.connect to dojo.connect; The rest of your code stays as is, see below.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function openAlert(evt) {
          alert("Hello!  This is an alert from Dojo!");
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="para">This is a paragraph.</p>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var para = dojo.byId("para");
        dojo.connect(para, "onclick", openAlert);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```